# Input type number validation

Tags: html, angular

I have input type number, I want to restrict it to only numbers between 1 and 2.
It can accept numbers between 0.00001 and 2 with decimal places up to 5 and not 0.

How do i do it? And also the user must not be able to write anything else manually.

I have tried min="1" and max="2" attributes but user is still able to type 0 manually and form is being submitted.

My project is based on angular 5 and I am using a template driven form. Please do not suggest solutions for reactive forms.

Comment: You can set calidation and show error accordingly

Comment: PardeepJain meant 'validation'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try regex also

If you want number in range of 1-2 with 5 decimals without number 2 then use pattern below,

[1]+(.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?

And if you want less than and equal to 2, you can set pattern as,

^(?:2|2.0|2.00|2.000|2.0000|2.00000 | (.[0]{1,2})?|([1])(.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?)$

For example:

```
<input class="form-control" 
           [(ngModel)]="data" name="dataModel" #dataModel="ngModel" required
           pattern="^(?:([2])(\.[0]*)? | (\.[0]{1,2})?|([1])(\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?)$">
    <div *ngIf="dataModel.errors && (dataModel.dirty || dataModel.touched)">
      <small [hidden]="!dataModel.errors.required">
        Required
      </small>
      <small [hidden]="!dataModel.errors.pattern">
        pattern check
      </small>         
    </div>
```

And if you want in range of 0-2 including 2 then you can set pattern as,

^(?:2|2.0|2.00|2.000|2.0000|2.00000 | (.[0]{1,2})?|([0-1])(.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?)$

If you want in range of 0-2 excluding 0 then pattern can be (this pattern accepts from 0.00001 to 2.00000 numbers),

^(2|2.0|2.00|2.000|2.0000|2.00000|([1]+(.?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?){1}|[0]+(.[0-9]{0,4}[1-9]{1})))$

Comment: `If you want number in range of 1-2 with 5 decimals without number 2`
i want to include 2 also, basically from 0.00001 to 2.

Comment: @Sushmit So you can go for second pattern

Comment: @Sushmit if you want between 0 and 2 then use pattern ^(?:2|2.0|2.00|2.000|2.0000|2.00000 | (.[0]{0,2})?|([1])(.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?)$

Comment: so it will not accept if number is less than 0 right ?

Comment: Yes, it will just accept number with 5 decimal digits within range 0-2

Comment: @Sushmit I have updated my answer, you can check now

Comment: seems to work now but one last thing. sorry to bother u. it shouldn't except 0. basically the range is 0.00001 to 2. appreciate ur help a lot. thanks

Comment: hi khush, i tried ^(2|2.0|2.00|2.000|2.0000|2.00000|([1]*(.[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?|[0]+.[0-9]{0,4}[1-9]{1}))$
but it is accepting 0.

Comment: @Sushmit try this ^(2|2.0|2.00|2.000|2.0000|2.00000|([1]+(.?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?){1}|[0]+(.[0-9]{0,4}[1-9]{1})))$

Comment: say in future if i need range from 0.00001 to 3 or any other number and replace all 2s with that number say 3 for example in your regex will it work as expected ?

Comment: No, you need to change pattern for that

Comment: oh ok. is there any way to generate such patterns easily without me having to post question on stack overflow each time ?

Comment: @Sushmit for that you have to learn regex. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<input type="number" step="0.00001" max="2" min="1" [(ngModel)]="data" #value="ngModel" required/>

<div *ngIf="value.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
     class="alert alert-danger">

  <div *ngIf="value.errors.required">
    Value is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="value.errors.min">
    Should not be less than 1
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="value.errors.max">
    Should not be greater than 2
  </div>

</div>
```

And validate your field for min and max values and display a error message.

Comment: it is saying identifier min is not defined. __type does not contain such a member

Answer (score 0):

> i have tried min="1" and max="2" attributes. but user is still able to
>   type 0 manually and form is being submitted.

you can use  `keydown` event here `(keydown)="false"` this will prevent the user to type anything, and still he will be able to use the arrow controls to increase and decrease the numbers.
I would suggest you to disable paste option too `(paste)="false"` to prevent  paste in the input field.

```
   <input type="number" step="0.00001" max="2" min="1" (keydown)="false" (paste)="false" required/>
```

Comment: but it will be painful if user has to type 0.0001 or something similar by using arrows.

Comment: yeah it will be :\

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a function for every keypress event and write your validation logic such that the user can enter only valid values.

```
<input type="number" step="0.00001" max="2" min="1" (keydown)="filterValue($event)" (paste)="false" required/>
```

Function :

```
  var filterValue = function($event){
     var keys={ 'up': 38,'right':39,'down':40,'left':37,                      
              'escape':27,'backspace':8,'tab':9,'enter':13,'del':46,                                
   '0':48,'1':49,'2':50,'3':51,'4':52,'5':53,'6':54,'7':55,'8':56,'9':57
         };
                   for(var index in keys) {
                            if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(index)) continue;
                            if ($event.charCode==keys[index]||$event.keyCode==keys[index]) {
                                return; //default event
                            }
                        }   
                        $event.preventDefault();
                 };
```

Define only required values in the keys object so that user will not be allowed to enter other values.

Comment: will this work for copy paste and in mozilla, IE11 also?